# Media query support for JS implementation of CSS Grid Template Layout

Tags: css, polyfills, grid-layout

The W3C has a [working draft](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css3-layout/) to introduce an advanced layout mechanism for HTML pages. I have found two JavaScript implementations that provide support in modern browsers for the fundamentals of this draft:

- https://github.com/acebal/ALMcss3/
- http://code.google.com/p/css-template-layout/

Does anyone know if either of these, or another implementation, includes support for adjusting the layout via media queries?